# Change color of specific points in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I have a scatterplot in Matlab and was wondering if there was any way to the change the color of just one of the points?

Comment: Does the solution work for you?

Comment: No, not really. It just puts a red dot in the middle of my point, I wanted to change the color of the actual point.

Comment: What's the difference in your visualization?!

Answer (score 2):

you can plot the graph, after that replot the point which you want.

```
   % plot the curve or graph
   hold on
   plot(x,y,'.r')
```

Try to `hold on` and then plot the point `(x,y)` which you want with the specified color (`r`) which you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to overlay a second plot on the first, you can plot each point individually and use handles. In that way, you can later perform arbitrary changes on each individual point.

You can find an example below.

```
% Generate some numbers
x = randn(10,1);
y = randn(10,1);

% Plot each point individually
figure
hold on
for idx = 1 : numel(x)
    hdl(idx) =  plot(x(idx),y(idx),'marker','.','color','k')
end

% change color, markerstyle, x-position, etc...
hdl(2).Color  = [1 0 0]
hdl(3).Marker  = 'o'
hdl(5).XData = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = rand(10,1) ;
y = rand(10,1) ;
scatter(x,y) ;

[x1,y1] = getpts ;

hold on
plot(x1,y1,'Or') ;
```

click on the point, you want to change color, when prompted.